# React Native: requestAnimationFrame is not supported in Node

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

**Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { StyleSheet, ListView } from 'react-native';
import Card from './card';

const styles = StyleSheet.create( {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
} );

export default class PhotoList extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    feeds: PropTypes.arrayOf( PropTypes.object ),
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    feeds: [],
  };

  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource( { rowHasChanged: ( r1, r2 ) => r1 !== r2 } );
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows( this.props.feeds ),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        enableEmptySections
        style={ styles.container }
        dataSource={ this.state.dataSource }
        renderRow={ feedItem => <Card feed={ feedItem } /> }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**__mocks__/react.js**

```
const react = require( 'react' );
// Resolution for requestAnimationFrame not supported in jest error :
// https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9102#issuecomment-283873039
global.window = global;
window.addEventListener = () => {};
window.requestAnimationFrame = () => {
  throw new Error( 'requestAnimationFrame is not supported in Node' );
};

module.exports = react;
```

**photo-list.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListView } from 'react-native';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import PhotoList from './photo-list';

const feed = {
  url: 'http://placehold.it/600x600',
  title: 'Some title for the card',
};

describe( '<PhotoList />', () => {
  it( 'should render without throwing an error', () => {
    const component = renderer.create(
      <PhotoList feed={ feed } />,
    ).toJSON();
    expect( component ).toMatchSnapshot();
  } );

  it( 'should contain a ListView', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow( <PhotoList feed={ feed } /> );
    expect( wrapper.find( ListView ).length ).toBe( 1 );
  } );
} );
```

Error:

```
 FAIL  src/components/photo-list.test.js
  ● Console

    console.error node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:71
      React caught an error thrown by ListView. You should fix this error in your code. Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

      Error: requestAnimationFrame is not supported in Node

      The error is located at:
          in ListView (created by PhotoList)
          in PhotoList

      The error was thrown at:
          at Object.<anonymous>.window.requestAnimationFrame (/Users/rahulshetty/localshiva/test-rn-apps/__mocks__/react.js:7:7),
          at Component.requestAnimationFrame (/Users/rahulshetty/localshiva/test-rn-apps/node_modules/react-timer-mixin/TimerMixin.js:16:14),
          at Component.componentDidMount (/Users/rahulshetty/localshiva/test-rn-apps/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CustomComponents/ListView/ListView.js:365:6),
          at commitLifeCycles (/Users/rahulshetty/localshiva/test-rn-apps/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactFiberCommitWork.js:421:24),
          at commitAllLifeCycles (/Users/rahulshetty/localshiva/test-rn-apps/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactFiberScheduler.js:349:9),
          at invokeGuardedCallback (/Users/rahulshetty/localshiva/test-rn-apps/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js:21:10),
          at invokeGuardedCallback (/Users/rahulshetty/localshiva/test-rn-apps/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js:91:34),
          at commitAllWork (/Users/rahulshetty/localshiva/test-rn-apps/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactFiberScheduler.js:468:19),
          at completeUnitOfWork (/Users/rahulshetty/localshiva/test-rn-apps/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactFiberScheduler.js:614:11),
          at performUnitOfWork (/Users/rahulshetty/localshiva/test-rn-apps/node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactFiberScheduler.js:641:14)
    console.warn node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:40
      Unable to symbolicate stack trace: this.dispatchEvent is not a function

  ● <PhotoList /> › should render without throwing an error

    requestAnimationFrame is not supported in Node

      at Object.<anonymous>.window.requestAnimationFrame (__mocks__/react.js:7:7)
      at Component.requestAnimationFrame (node_modules/react-timer-mixin/TimerMixin.js:16:14)
      at Component.componentDidMount (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CustomComponents/ListView/ListView.js:365:6)
      at commitLifeCycles (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactFiberCommitWork.js:421:24)
      at commitAllLifeCycles (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactFiberScheduler.js:349:9)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js:21:10)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js:91:34)
      at commitAllWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactFiberScheduler.js:468:19)
      at completeUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactFiberScheduler.js:614:11)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/lib/ReactFiberScheduler.js:641:14)
```

**Issue:**

I'm new to testing and I have set-up a React Native project using Create React Native App to understand unit testing. I'm not sure what's causing this error. All I wish is to test if `ListView` exists in my component. How can I add support for `requestAnimationFrame`?

Answer (score 1):

You could just put:

```
if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) {
  let targetTime = 0
  window.requestAnimationFrame = function (callbackFun) {
    const currentTime = +new Date()
    const timeoutCb = function () { callbackFun(+new Date()) }
    return window.setTimeout(timeoutCb, Math.max(targetTime + 16, currentTime) - currentTime)
  }
}
```

into your code to polifill requestAnimationFrame in node. I'm assuming that you're using jsdom so you already have window. Ofc code can be simpler if you don't want to simulate behavior and you can extract it outside your test for clearer code.